# Azure pipeline failed for a second step due to private npm registry permissions denied

Tags: azure, npm, azure-pipelines, registry

We have a .NET application with an integrated SPA (React) and 4 environments (separated Azure subscriptions with app services), Prod/Test/Sandbox/Dev. Our frontend application use a library from a private registry, so in the ClientApp root, we have an `.npmrc` file with the configuration:

```
@company:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/company-npm/npm/registry
always-auth=true
```

App.Backend.API.csproj:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install /> // this is the second run
</Target >
```

The problem is that for 2 of the environments (`prod/test`) the pipeline is able to install the private library, but for `dev/sandbox` it is not, getting `401 unauthenticated`. If I set a registry token (PAT), based on my user, the error response is changed to `403 (no permissions)`. 3 months ago, when we created these environments, this problem didn't exist.

The "in cause" steps from pipeline looks like below. It's strange why the first `npm install` works but the second one (from `App.Backend.API.csproj` throws the error).

```
stages:
   - stage: Build
     jobs:
        - job: build
          steps:
            - checkout: self

            - task: Npm@1
              inputs:
                command: 'install'

            ...
    
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 // containing the second 'npm install'
              displayName: 'Publish'
              inputs:
                command: 'publish'
                zipAfterPublish: true
```

What I'm thinking:

- the same source code works for 2 environments but not for other 2, which means that users/environments/services (on Azure DevOps) have different permissions for this private registry. DevOps teams reported that they made changes to some services, but ensured that all permissions were granted to access the private registry;
- maybe still working prod/test environments use a cached `.npmrc` that had a valid token; For that... I checked the logs and everything seems pretty ok (the current file from the project is used) // *or maybe there is a global `.npmrc` (which should be replaced by a project-provided npmrc anyway), but we can only check using `ls` in the pipeline steps, because we don't have access to the server running the pipeline*;
- differences: the first `npm install` is run by a `node` process, while the second is run by a `dotnet` process: maybe something to check more here;

Having the same source code and `.npmrc` configuration on all environments, I tried everything to understand the problem, but no luck. If anyone had this problem or knows how to debug the issue better, I'd appreciate it.

thanks